# Table doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

I try to perform this SQL on a MYSQL 8.0.18 server:

```
SELECT `information_schema`.* FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` WHERE `information_schema`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'DB_NAME' ORDER BY `information_schema`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` LIMIT 0, 25
```

but get this error:

**#1051 - Unknown table 'information_schema'**

Which should be there hence it is a standard MySQL database, it works IF I remove `information_schema` from the SQL and select the database 'information_schema'. 
My problem is I just wish to connect and then perform the SQL to retrieve table for a specific database.

Comment: Example of ambiguity present now: retrieve table or contents of a table? If you're retrieving a table to, for example, link it to a grid, then use a data aware component like a dataset, datasource, table, etc. If you want the contents then just `select * from tableName`

Comment: Either `SELECT *` or `SELECT `information_schema.TABLES.*`, not intermediate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is referring to `information_shcema` as a table, rather than a database. The table `information_schema` doesn't exist. You want something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES`
WHERE `TABLES`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'DB_NAME'
ORDER BY `TABLES`.`TABLE_SCHEMA`
LIMIT 0, 25
```

Note I've removed `information_schema` from the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clause.

Your `ORDER BY` is ordering by the same field you're filtering by, so will have no effect.

Comment: Thanks ... Just what I couldn't see myself :-)